# Generating defined rectangles (size, position) as a new shapefile layer in distance to specific points from another shapefile layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, rectangle, layer-to-kml

I'm familiar with the basics of QGIS, but now I'm confronted with a difficult task.

I want to create a new shapefile (as a layer) which contains defined rectangles (size, position) from another layer with specific points.

These points are single points (coordinates of places for instance). The rectangles should be something like a labelling field.

If possible, I want to connect the generated labelling field layer to aggregated information from a third layer. But this is only optional. At last, I want to export the labelling field as KML-file (with MMQGIS for instance).

**Background**

I tried buffering methods with the point-layer as well as the symbology implemented geometry generator. I also tried specific labelling from the symbology. I was satisfied with the first results of the last mentioned methods.

Unfortunately, it wasn't possible to export the "virtual" rectangles as KML. I couldn't find a suitable plugin for this task. Maybe I have to think about PyQGIS.

Fortunately, I got **some (rough) ideas** to deal with this task:

1. Read coordinates from the points (point-layer)
2. Generate "virtual" rectangle coordinates in relation to the point-coordinates (size + position)
3. Create a new shapefile layer with rectangles from the generated "virtual" rectangle coordinates and save it
4. Export the layer as KML

**Optional**

5. Connect the shapes with aggregated field values of a third layer, save it and export it as KML (I know the single steps, but maybe there is something like a compound function?)

See the wished result (1-3) made by "hand":

[image: Wished_result]

Maybe someone could help me with that. Would be great!

Comment: Try the `geometry by expression` tool. If you got the geometry generator to produce the desired outcome, put the same expression into this tool.